# Jboss 7.1.1 IllegalArgumentException: Empty name segment is not allowed for env

Tags: java, jboss

I've got

> Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment
>
> (...)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty name segment is not allowed for env
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName.of(ServiceName.java:85) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName.append(ServiceName.java:112) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

When trying to deploy a jar containing MDB during Arquillian testing. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the example [Arquillian *Testing JMS* section](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/1.0.0.Alpha2/en-US/html/examples.html#examples.jms) which had

```
@Resource(mappedName = "/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory factory;
```

It looks like resource name path cannot contain empty parts. I added `jms` prefix and it deploys fine.

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory factory;
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be issue with ear structure, check jboss-app.xml
all modules should be valid, need to avoid examples like this:

```
<module>
    <service><!-- [INSERT SERVICE NAME HERE] --></service>
</module>
```

Or duplication jboss-app, like jboss-appp-ref.xml etc.

Also all JNDI names should have segment depends on EE 6 spec.
In Annotations, Lookups etc.
Standard:

```
java:/yourJndiName
```

PS: there's jboss 7 recommendation to use resources name segment like:

```
java:jboss/datasources/yourDataSource
java:jboss/mail/yourMailSource
```